# Basis of the field $E$=$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5})$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let's take a field $E$=$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5})$.

I wanted to find a basis of $E$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspace.
My first thought was to use the structure theorem for simply field extension. Therefore I needed to find an element $u\in E$ so that $u$ is algebraïc over $E$ and a $f$ so that $f(u)=0$. Then would $u,u^{2},...,u^{deg(f)-1}$ be a basis. I just don't know how I can do this correctly.

Second I wanted find a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ so that $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Because I'm stuck with my first thought I don't understand how I can find such an $f$.

EDIT:

FIRTS

- let's name $\alpha$=$\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5}$. We're looking for a polynomal $f\in \mathbb{Q}$  so that $f(\alpha)$=0.

$\alpha^{2}$=$-1-2i\sqrt{30}$

$\alpha^{3}$=$-i\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{+}\sqrt{30}+2i\sqrt{5}\sqrt{0}$

$\alpha^{4}$=$1+4i\sqrt{30}-120$=$-119+4i\sqrt{30}$

Then follows that $\alpha^{4}+2\alpha^{2}+121=0$

we name $f(x)$=$x^{4}+2x^{2}+121$

Because $f$ isn't $0$ and has no points $x$ so $f(x)=0$ , is $f$ irriducibel.
This means that $f$ is the minimal polynomal of $\alpha$ over $E$. Now we use the theorem of structure for simply field extension and it follows that {$1,\alpha,\alpha^{2},\alpha^{3}$} is a basis.

SECOND

- I'm still stuck proving this

Comment: There are infinite basis on a vecteur field. $\{1,\alpha ,\alpha ^2,\alpha ^3\}$ is a basis, and $\{1,-\sqrt 6, \sqrt 5, i\sqrt{30}\}$ is an other one. But both are differents.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5)^2=-1-2\sqrt{30}i$$
and thus $$((\sqrt6i-\sqrt 5)^2+1)^2+120=0,$$
i.e. $$x^4+2x^2+121=0$$
is an annilhator polynomial. I let you conclude.

---

An other way would be to show that $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i,\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5),$$ and thus, a basis would be $$\{1,\sqrt 6i,\sqrt 5, i\sqrt{30}\}.$$

Comment: what is an annilhator polynomial?

Comment: Why you calculate ($\sqrt{6}i+\sqrt{5}$)$^{2}$ and not  ($\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5}$)$^{2}$

Comment: I tried to do you're second hint by making an morfism between the two fields , but i can't make it work

Comment: @mathmath: I correct it, but the final polynomial is unchanged. For the second method, the fact that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i,\sqrt 5)$ is obvious. For the converse inclusion, notice that $\sqrt{6i}+\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{6i}-\sqrt 5)$ (why ?). And thus, for example, $\sqrt 5=\frac{\sqrt 6i+\sqrt 5-(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5)}{2}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5).$ I let you prove that $\sqrt 6i\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6i-\sqrt 5)$ and thus the equality follow.

Comment: I can't see how you become your basis?

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $p(x)=x^2-5$. And the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ is $q(x)= x^2+2\sqrt{5}x +11$.

You can then use telescopic basis theorem to get that a basis of $E$ over $\mathbb Q$ is

$$\{1, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{6}i, \sqrt{30}i\}$$

Comment: You’re right. I miscalculated products. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

For part two of your question. You already found the right polynomial, i.e. $f(x)=x^4+2x^2+121$. You know that $\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5}$ is a root of this polynomial. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and has characteristic 0, you know from Primitive element theorem that your Splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: Wikipedia page of primitive element theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: In dutch it is called: Stelling van het primitive element.(Zie pagina 115)

Comment: By the way, veel succes morgen met je examen! :D

Comment: The primitive element theorem states that there is a $c \in \mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ being the roots of $f$, such that $\mathbb Q(c)=\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, but it does not say that $c=\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5}$. Nevertheless, the correct answer is indeed $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5})$. PS. jij ook succes morgen!

Comment: How would you prove $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{6}i-\sqrt{5})
$ is the spitting field?